# Left Join on same table multiples times with 2 ids with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have this SQL request:

```
SELECT mailbox.*,
       user.picture, user.firstname, user.lastname
FROM mailbox 
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = mailbox.sender_id
WHERE mailbox.sender_id = 54 OR mailbox.receiver_id = 54
```

And I need another `LEFT JOIN` on receiver_id like that:

```
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = mailbox.receiver_id
```

getting infos from user, but I already get infos from user with my first `LEFT JOIN`

So how could get infos from user table another time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT m.*,
       us.picture, us.firstname, us.lastname,
       ur.picture, ur.firstname, ur.lastname
FROM mailbox m LEFT JOIN
     user us
     ON us.id = m.sender_id LEFT JOIN
     user ur
     ON ur.id = m.receiver_id 
WHERE 54 IN (m.sender_id, m.receiver_id);
```

Note:  You probably don't need `LEFT JOIN` here.  The receiver and sender id columns presumably contain valid user values.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, then this should work:

```
SELECT mailbox.*, u1.picture, u1.firstname, u1.lastname, u2.picture, u2.user.firstname, u2.lastname
FROM mailbox 
LEFT JOIN user u1 ON u1.id = mailbox.sender_id
LEFT JOIN user u2 ON u2.id = mailbox.receiver_id
WHERE mailbox.sender_id = 54 OR mailbox.receiver_id = 54
```